# Why my ng-template not showing the value of $scope and ng-repeat in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a problem now regarding my ng-template.

This is my Code:

**HTML:**

```
<script id="templates/popover.html" type="text/ng-template">
    <ion-popover-view>
    <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
        <a class="item" ng-repeat="chap in Chapters">
            {{chap}}
        </a>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
    </ion-popover-view>
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.Chapters = [1,2,3,4];
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html', function (popover) {
        $scope.popover = popover;
    });
```

I have like that im working with `Ionic Popover' from this site http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/GpCst

Why my ng-repeat not showing anything..

Please help me.. Thank you

Comment: I believe because it has its own scope? Try copying $scope.Chapters to a temp var, like chapters, and then INSIDE the function, do $scope.Chapters = chapters;

Comment: No, I'm wrong, but I have an answer, give me 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Popover function lets you pass in a scope value. I forked the Pen to do so:

http://codepen.io/cfjedimaster/pen/thaim

The basic change is here:

```
$scope.Chapters = [1,2,3];
$ionicPopover.fromTemplateUrl('templates/popover.html',{scope:$scope}).then(function(popover) {
    $scope.popover = popover;
});
```

Make sense?